# shell variable value in for loop different after loop

Tags: shell-script, hp-ux, tee

I have a challenge with a variable value changed in a for loop and the value of that variable after the for  loop  and using tee

SCRIPT_1:

```
    STATUS=9
    for  SESSION in  A B C
    do
       STATUS=5
       echo "SESSION=$SESSION  STATUS=$STATUS"
    done 
    echo "STATUS=$STATUS"
```

output script_1 is:

```
    SESSION=A  STATUS=5
    SESSION=B  STATUS=5
    SESSION=C  STATUS=5
    STATUS=5
```

SRIPT_2:

```
    STATUS=9
    for  SESSION in  A B C
    do
       STATUS=5
       echo "SESSION=$SESSION  STATUS=$STATUS"
    done | tee /tmp/ses.txt
    echo "STATUS=$STATUS"
```

output_2 is:

```
    SESSION=A  STATUS=5
    SESSION=B  STATUS=5
    SESSION=C  STATUS=5
    STATUS=9
```

Why a different output when using tee after done command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put a "| tee", the shell that is interpreting the script is forking a new shell for the loop.
Inserting a sleep in the loop and launching the script in background gives this list of processes:

```
   PID TTY       TIME COMMAND
 21168 pts/0     0:00 sh
 21259 pts/0     0:00 ps
 11962 pts/0     0:00 sh
 21170 pts/0     0:00 sleep
 21171 pts/0     0:00 tee
 21169 pts/0     0:00 sh
```

As you can see, there is an additional shell at the end of the list. You can get the same result with this script:

```
STATUS=9
echo "" > /tmp/ses.txt
for  SESSION in  A B C
do
   STATUS=5
   echo "SESSION=$SESSION  STATUS=$STATUS" | tee -a /tmp/ses.txt
done
echo "STATUS=$STATUS"
```

but whitout the side effect you are mentioning.

Comment: More exactly, piping to anything (not just `tee`) runs in a subshell. I don't know what shell(s?) hp-ux uses, but bash ksh93 zsh have another option: `for blah blah done > >(tee foo)` works as a simple redirection not a pipe and thus sets the var(s) in the original shell.